# I don't know why my 'if' statement isn't working

Tags: python

I am trying to make a game with a user leveling system and I am having trouble because the program won't check whether my list (exp (experience)) has a certain value.  To do this, I am using an if statement because i need the program to update a different list if exp = 1:

```
from random import*
import random

ulvl = ["1"]
exp = ["0"]
f = randint(1, 1)
print("f = ", f)
exp.clear()
exp.insert(0, f)
print("you currently have", exp, "exp. point(s)")

if exp == "1":
    ulvl = ulvl+1
    ulvl.clear()
    ulvl.insert(ulvl)
else:
    print("u broke it")

print(ulvl)
```

ulvl = User Level, f = experience earned from fighting.
I have made f always = 1 to test whether it actually works... which is doesn't... when exp = 1, the ulvl should update to the current ulvl + 1 and insert that into the ulvl list and remove the last number.

Comment: `exp` is a list with one element, `"1"` is a string. They can never be equal.

Comment: You need to use `if "1" in exp:` to check because `exp` is a list.

Comment: Going off of the comment by @MichaelButscher you need to choose the first element from the list you are using (index 0).

Comment: You may not want lists at all for `ulvl` and `exp`, just integers (without `"` nor brackets): `ulvl = 1`, `exp = 0` and `if exp == 1:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others are saying you should not be using lists for this and just keeping ulvl and exp as ints, but if you have another reason to keep them as list then the following will make your if statement work.

```
if exp == [1]:
```

You then run into further problems though because you cannot do,

```
ulvl = ulvl+1
```

So I think this will work in your current form,

```
from random import*
import random

ulvl = ["1"]
exp = ["0"]
f = randint(1, 1)
print("f = ", f)
exp.clear()
exp.insert(0, f)
print("you currently have", exp, "exp. point(s)")

if exp == [1]:
    ulvlnew = 2
    ulvl.clear()
    ulvl.insert(0, ulvlnew)
else:
    print("u broke it")

print(ulvl)
```

This returns a ulvl of [2] but as you can see the 2 is hard coded, because you are using lists you are really restricting yourself.

what you should really do is this.

```
ulvl = 1
exp = 1
print("you currently have", exp, "exp. point(s)")

if exp == 1:
    ulvl = ulvl + 1
else:
    print("u broke it")

print(ulvl)
```

This returns a ulvl of 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the error. When you execute your code, this comes up:

```
f =  1
you currently have [1] exp. point(s)
u broke it
['1']
```

When I removed exp.clear(), this came out:

```
f =  1  
you currently have [1, '0'] exp. point(s)  
u broke it  
['1']
```

Hopefully this helps for your erros.